# flexbox javascript dynamic loading from cms

Tags: javascript, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox in Javascript to load a number of projects from my CMS.. 
There should be 3 images that represent projects per row, hence I defined a flexbox with row wrap property..

The container element has a fixed width and height, and so I would expect the loop to run 4 times, create 4 items that are stacked in a row with the last one starting at the next row.. What I am getting in the code snippet is 4 items with full screen width. What I am getting on my screen with real pictures is 1 picture, that's it..

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```js
    var flexbox_projects = document.createElement("div");
    flexbox_projects.className = "flex-container";
    flexbox_projects.id = "flexbox_projects";
    document.getElementById("body").appendChild(flexbox_projects);


    for (i=0; i<4; i++){

      var container_project = document.createElement("div");
      container_project.className = "container_project";
     document.getElementById("flexbox_projects").appendChild(container_project);

      var image_project = document.createElement("img");
      image_project.className = "main_picture";
      image_project.src = "img/trailrun.jpg";
      container_project.appendChild(image_project);

    }
```

```css
.container_project{
    width: 23vw;
    height: 13vw;
}

.main_picture{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}


.flex-container{

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

}
```

```html
<body id="body">

</body>
```

Comment: I think it's because `// PROJECT STYLING ` and `// PROJECT CONTAINING FLEXBOX STYLING ` are not valid comments

Comment: You are right.. Difficult to explain, but thanks! :-)

Comment: I posted as answer so you can accept it and close the question, it would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments

> I think it's because // PROJECT STYLING and // PROJECT CONTAINING
>   FLEXBOX STYLING are not valid comments

If you want to comment in CSS use `/* my comment */`